# Что такое thenable объект?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, терминология, promise

Что такое **thenable** и как он используется?

Comment: _thenable (i.e. has a "then" method)_ - _thenable (т.е. есть метод "then")_ -> любой объект имеющий метод `then` может считаться `thenable`.

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить источник, в котором упоминается этот термин, чтобы был ясен контекст.

Comment: thenable - просто интерфейс, у которого есть метод then. Точка. Никаким стандартам он следовать не обязан. В определённых ситуациях, thenable: `{then(...args){/*...*/}}` способен частично заменить Promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thenable этот тот же [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), например, потому что он имеет метод then в виде [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

Как подметил **vp_arth**:

> henable не обязан быть полноценным Promise.

Так, например, [Promise.resolve(value)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) работает по такой логике:

> if the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned
>   promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state;
>   otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value

Если `value` это промис, то возвращаемый промис(возвращает `Promise.resolve`) будет следовать логике промиса в аргументе `value`.

Пример:

```js
// тут then будет выполнять then для new Promise
Promise.resolve(
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Выполнился через секунду'))
).then(value => console.log(value))
```

Иначе будет возвращен промис с уже выполненным значением:

```js
// тут передается промис с выполненым(resolve) значением
Promise.resolve('Выполнился через секунду').then(value => console.log(value))
```

Comment: хорошо обьяснил держи плюс :)

Comment: Thenable не обязан быть полноценным Promise.

Comment: @vp_arth согласен, можно реализовать свое подобие промиса, например взяв prototype в Promise.prototype

Answer (score 4):

Javascript включает реализацию [спецификации Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/)

Согласно этой спецификации термин `thenable` означает следующее:

> “thenable” is an object or function that defines a then method.

> “thenable” – это объект или функция, в которых определен метод `then`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Promise.resolve(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve):

> if the value is a **thenable** (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned
>   promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state;
>   otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value

Если у промиса есть `then`, то вся цепочка выполнится. Если `then` нет, то сразу вернётся значение.

```js
// сначала выполнится вся цепочка промиса, а потом вернётся результат
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
}).then(res => res));

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // выведет: Array [1, 2, 3]
});


// сразу получаем результат
var promise2 = Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3]);

promise2.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // выведет: Array [1, 2, 3]
});
```

Comment: А зачем `.then(res => res));`?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько для наглядности. Если убрать, то ничего не изменится)

Comment: ответ не очень лично я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Избытоксусликов может не в ответе дело?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов я вроде лучше объяснли